# How declare and assign value to a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I need to have two variables and want to perform an addition with these variables in shell script.

I am using the below script for this, but I get an `expr: non-numeric argument error` while running the same.

```
#!/bin/sh
val1=10
val2=20
while [val1 -gt 5]
do
echo $val1
val1=$(expr $VAL + $BAL)
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
while [val1 -gt 5]
```

It should be:

```
while [ $val1 -gt 5 ]
```

… because:

- You need the dollar sign in `$val1` to refer to the variable.
- You need a space between the bracket `[` and the variable. It's a command, and otherwise the shell would first expand `$val1` to its value `10` and then would search for the command `[10`, which it obviously can not find.

Apart from that, your script should work in theory, but neither `$VAL` nor `$BAL` are defined, so it's understandable that you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will this script work fine if i replace `$VAL` and `$BAL` with `$val1` and `$val2`

Comment: Yes. Although it doesn't make a lot of sense because the loop will never exit ;)

Comment: Oops! As i am newbie to shell scripting, i was trying an arithmetic operation. Its really exciting!!